# How to subclass an UIViewController with UITableViewDelegate in many subclasses

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I would like to have a reusable view controller called MainViewController with a UITableView inside.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.scrollsToTop = true

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 124.0
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

[image: MainViewController]

I need to have many subclasses of my MainViewController, to can custom them depending of my needs. IntroViewController is one of them.

```
class IntroViewController: MainViewController {

}
```

To open the IntroViewController, here my segue:

[image: UINavigationController]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "intro" {

        let destination =  segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let ivc = destination.topViewController as! IntroViewController
    }

}
```

I got this crash:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

for the line

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

I checked, my outlets are linked correctly. Datasource too.

Comment: what is StoryViewController ?

Comment: MainViewController, I corrected.

Comment: why navigation controller between 2 controllers.?

Comment: Have you given your class name to table controller.?

Comment: I could be used a custom segue instead the navigation controller

Comment: Yes I have given the class name to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't really work that way. The @IBOutlets are all connected through the Storyboard - but they don't "flow through" in the pattern you're hoping to use.

You *can* do it - in a way. Take a look a the discussion and answers in this SO post: [How to subclass custom UIViewController in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809240/how-to-subclass-custom-uiviewcontroller-in-swift)

Alternatively, if you're goal is to use a "common" table view controller - but allow customization - you can create separate `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` files, plus separate visually designed cells, and then assign them via code as desired.